# tikz drawing a partitioned rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

I would like to draw the following figure, but I don't even know where to begin. This goes far beyond my tikz expertise. If anyone can help, I would appreciate it very much. Here is a skeleton code to get the rectangle going:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[rectangle,draw,minimum width=2in,minimum height=2in,thick,text width=2in] (box1) {Type-B adaptable\\Type-B adaptable\\Type-C robust\\Type-B adaptable\\Type-A robust\\Type-A adaptable\\Type-B adaptable\\Type-C adaptable};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could at least post code for the rectangle with some nodes containing the text inside.

Comment: I can certainly post the code for the rectangle, but the real problem is that I do not know how to construct "some nodes containing the text inside" -- that is why I am asking for help.

Comment: Right now, you require anybody who wants to help to start with `\documentclass` and do all the laborious setting up of the basic structure of the document. You are making it more effortful to help you in ways which people will know are quite unnecessary since you could very easily do *that* part for yourself. Just type the text you want in nodes somewhere even if they aren't in the rectangle. Don't make people copy from your image. That's tedious and error-prone.

Comment: Fair enough -- did not think that sufficiently I suppose. I have created a sample with the rectangle and the text. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: OK. Could you say what you aren't sure about? I guess you know how to draw curves and lines (based on your previous questions) and how to put text in nodes. I guess I'm a bit unsure what you're stuck on and need help with.

Comment: I can draw curves, but I am not sure how to draw them within the rectangle and declare them as nodes.

Comment: I don't think you can declare them as nodes (though I'm not sure). However, you could `clip` to the rectangle. Then put the nodes in with the text. Then draw the curves around the nodes. If everything is within a scope which clips the content, you won't have to worry about staying within the bounds of the rectangle.

Comment: Sorry,but I don't follow this. I will study clip tomorrow to see what it does.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is one solution. The curves are drawn via

draw[] (A).. controls (B) .. (C); 
   draw[] (C) to[out=xx,in=yy] (E);

and the shaded line areas are done via `clip` skill with `scope` environment. Further the text are place via tikz node. Several style macros were predefined including the B/W shading.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{rec/.style={thick,text width=2cm,font=\bfseries\large,align=left, text opacity=1},
line/.style={dashed, line width=2pt},
sharea/.style={shade, left color=gray!50, right color=white} % B/W shading
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\path[sharea](-0.2,-0.2) rectangle (5.2,5.2);
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
% north west lines area
\fill[pattern=north west lines,opacity=0.2] (1.8,3.8) to [out=-120,in=90] (2.5,0)--(0,0)--(0,3); % blue line to the left
\fill[pattern=north west lines,opacity=0.2] (0,5)--(3.7,5).. controls (3,2.5) .. (0,1.5)-- cycle; % Yellow line to the left
\fill[white] (3,5) to[out=-135,in=15] (1.8,3.8) to [out=-200, in=35] (0,3.4) --(0,5)--(3,5); 
\path[sharea] (3,5) to[out=-135,in=15] (1.8,3.8) to [out=-200, in=35] (0,3.4) --(0,5)--(3,5); 
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (1.8,3.8) to[out=-120,in=90](2.5,0)--(0,0)--(0,5)--(3,5)--cycle; 
\fill[white] (3.7,5).. controls (3,2.5) .. (0,1.5)-- (0,5); 
\path[sharea] (3.7,5).. controls (3,2.5) .. (0,1.5)-- (0,5);left
\end{scope}

%\path[draw] (0,0) grid (5,5);

\draw[line] (3,5) to[out=-135,in=15](1.8,3.8) to [out=-200, in=35] (0,3.4);
\draw[line] (1.8,3.8) to[out=-120,in=90](2.5,0);
\draw[line] (3.7,5).. controls (3,2.5) .. (0,1.5);
\draw[line] (5,2.5) to[out=-180,in=10] (2.6,2.6);
\draw[line] (4.2,2.5) to[out=-90,in=90] (4,0);
\draw[line] (4,1) to[out=160,in=0] (2.3,1);

% node to place text
\node[rec] at (1.2,0.8)           {Type-A, \\ robust};
\node[rec] at (2.5,3.3)           {Type-C, \\ robust};
\node[rec] at (3,1.8)             {Type-A, \\ adaptable};
\node[rec] at (1,4.5)             {Type-B, \\ adaptable};
\node[rec,rotate=40] at (0.8,2.5) {Type-B, \\ adaptable};
\node[rec,rotate=40] at (4.2,4)   {Type-B, \\ adaptable};
\node[rec] at (3.2,0.5)           {Type-B, \\ adaptable};
\node[rec,rotate=80] at (4.5,1)   {Type-C, \\ adaptable};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this; this is great. The ode has a lot of stuff that I will study -- it will teach me greatly. Thanks again.

Comment: @ozsu you are welcome. Glad it helps.