# figure TIKZ with a parition of a rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, function

I wanna create a standalone tikz file of :

[image]

It is a partition into sets with smooth boundary and each set has a color either red or green.

This is what I ve done so far (with circles):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-4,-1) rectangle (4,4); % E
\draw (0,0) ++(45:2) circle (0.5); % B
\fill[color=green!30] \E;
\fill[opacity=0.5,red] \A;
\fill[opacity=0.5,red] \B;
\fill[opacity=0.5,red] \C;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

with

```
\newcommand{\E}{(-4,-1) rectangle (4,4)}
\newcommand{\A}{(0,0) ++(135:3) circle (0.7)}
\newcommand{\B}{(0,0) ++(45:1) circle (0.7)}
\newcommand{\C}{(0,0) ++(50:3.5) circle (1)}
```

Do you have some ideas? thanks in advance

Comment: With a quick Google search, I found this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197410/47927  which may be of some help